# JavaScript Function causing loop to end?

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with my function and loop and not sure why.

```js
var a = ['1,0,1', '0,1,0', '1,1,1'];
var b = [1, 1, 1];

function myFunction() {
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var user = a[i].split(',');
    var cs = cosinesim(user, b);
    document.getElementById("cs").innerHTML += String(user) + '  ' + String(cs) + '<br>';
    cs = 0;
    user = '';
  }
}

function cosinesim(A, B) {
  var dotproduct = 0;
  var mA = 0;
  var mB = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    dotproduct += (parseInt(A[i]) * parseInt(B[i]));
    mA += (parseInt(A[i]) * parseInt(A[i]));
    mB += (parseInt(B[i]) * parseInt(B[i]));
  }
  mA = Math.sqrt(mA);
  mB = Math.sqrt(mB);
  if ((mA * mB) == 0) {
    var similarity = 0
  } else {
    var similarity = (dotproduct) / (mA * mB)
  }

  return similarity;
}
```

```html
<p id="cs"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

I am trying to get the function to loop through the a array and print out the cosine similarity for each element in the array, however it only prints the first? If I remove the cs variable and calculations, the function prints out all the users. I am not sure why adding the cosine function within the function causes it to only run once?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: replace `i = 0` with `var i = 0` in your loops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the same (global) variable `i` in both functions. You should declare `i` as a local variable in each:

```
var i;
```

or in the `for` loops:

```
for (var i = 0; ...
```

Because both loops currently use the same `i`, once the `cosinesim()` function runs, the loop in the first function will be over too.

If you code in "strict" mode, you get an error from such implicit global uses.

Comment: Thanks, did not know it would have created a global variable.

Comment: Using a let instead of a var would further improve the scoping of 'i', in case @Future expands his code.

Comment: @gkgkgkgk yes, true, though old versions of IE and the old Android browser don't support it. That's getting much less important as time goes on of course.